# Forming custom dice with given joint distribution

Tags: probability-or-statistics, combinatorica

I am interested in the following problem.

I want to decorate the faces of $n$ six-sided dice with integers, such that (as closely as possible, for some reasonable definition of "close") they satisfy various constraints on their joint distributions. All else being equal, I would prefer these integers being small.

e.g. I would like three dice $A,B,C$ such that

> $$\mathbf{P}(A>0) =1/2,$$
> $$ \  \mathbf{P}(A+B>0) = 2/3,$$
> $$ \mathbf{P}(A+B+C>0)=5/6,$$ $$\mathbf{P}(A=0) =0,$$

or as close as possible to that.

How might one code this in Mathematica?

---

*Edit:* I am asking for a **general** method that works for any $n$ and reasonable set of restrictions on the joint distribution, and suggest that the answerer apply the general method in the simple example I gave, where it is easy to compute an answer directly by hand.

Comment: One solution to your example is $(-1,-1,-1,1,1,1)$, $(-2,-2,2,2,2,2)$, $(-4,4,4,4,4,4)$. But I do not have Mathematica code that generates this.

Comment: For a small number of dice, faces, values on the faces you can use `Tuples` or nested `For` and generate some or all the possible dice and then write a function that takes one set of the dice and tests whether that set is acceptable or not. If you use `Tuples` then you can use `Select` to extract the acceptable sets.  Does this give you an idea how you might start? Start with a really easy example to test this first and then work closer to your actual problem.

Comment: Not sure what you're expecting when you ask "how might one code this?". But, if you're wanting to experiment, a useful function might be EmpiricalDistribution. For example, `DistributionA=EmpiricalDistribution[{-1,-1,-1,1,1,1}]`. You can do the same for the B and C dice. Then you can use TransformedDistribution: `DistributionAPlusB=TransformedDistribution[a+b,{a\[Distributed]DistributionA,b\[Distributed]DistributionB}]`. You can test probabilities like this: `Probability[x > 0, x \[Distributed] DistributionAPlusB]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code:

```
(* General *)
alldice[{nfaces_,min_,max_}]:=Select[Tuples[Range[min,max],nfaces],OrderedQ];
findBruteForce[admissibleDice_,ndice_,diceinfo:{nfaces_,min_,max_}]:=Catch[
   Outer[If[admissibleDice[##],Throw[{##}]]&,
         Sequence@@ConstantArray[alldice[diceinfo],ndice],1];{}];

(* Example *)
Pevent1[dice1_,dice2_,dice3_]:=1/Length[dice1]*Count[dice1,0];
Pevent2[dice1_,dice2_,dice3_]:=1/Length[dice1]*Count[dice1,_?Positive];
Pevent3[dice1_,dice2_,dice3_]:=1/Length[dice1]*1/Length[dice2]*Count[Outer[Plus,dice1,dice2],_?Positive,{2}];
Pevent4[dice1_,dice2_,dice3_]:=1/Length[dice1]*1/Length[dice2]*1/Length[dice3]*Count[Outer[Plus,dice1,dice2,dice3],_?Positive,{3}];

admissibleDiceExample[tol_]:=And[
  Abs[Pevent1[##]-0]<tol,
  Abs[Pevent2[##]-1/2]<tol,
  Abs[Pevent3[##]-2/3]<tol,
  Abs[Pevent4[##]-5/6]<tol]&;
```

Search among all dice with 6 faces and numbers from $-1$ to $2$, runs in less than a second:

```
dice123 = findBruteForce[admissibleDiceExample[0.01],3,{6,-1,2}]
(* {{-1,-1,-1,1,1,1},{-1,-1,2,2,2,2},{1,1,1,1,1,1}} *)
```

I used a small tolerance, but this happens to be an exact solution:

```
Pevent1@@dice123
(* 0 *)

Pevent2@@dice123
(* 1/2 *)

Pevent3@@dice123
(* 2/3 *)

Pevent4@@dice123
(* 5/6 *)
```

The `Pevent` functions look a little complicated. But they use `Outer[Plus,...]` which may be faster than some other approaches.

Answer (score 0):

With the answer from user29378 you may get a solution that is close enough to what you want:

```
d1 = {-1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1};
d2 = {-2, -2, 2, 2, 2, 2};
d3 = {-4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4};
dis1 = EmpiricalDistribution[d1];
dis2 = EmpiricalDistribution[d2];
dis3 = EmpiricalDistribution[d3];
```

To test this we may use RandomVariate to generate samples from the distribution, count how many are o.k. and calculate the probability:

```
n = 10^6;
Count[RandomVariate[dis1, n], x_ /; x > 0]/n // N
Count[RandomVariate[dis1, n] + RandomVariate[dis2, n], x_ /; x > 0]/n // N
Count[RandomVariate[dis1, n] + RandomVariate[dis2, n] +  RandomVariate[dis3, n], x_ /; x > 0]/n // N
```

[image]

Comment: This doesn't really answer my question - to be clear, for each small example I am perfectly able to come up with custom dice by hand, and compute the probabilities. I was asking for a *general* method, and suggesting that the answerer apply the general method in the simple example I gave, where it is easy to compute an answer directly by hand.

Comment: And what probabilities should a general method have?